# A WinSCP script to download, rename, and move files

Tags: ftp, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

<sup>*Disclaimer #1: I posted this question on the WinSCP's [forum](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=81727) but haven't received any replies and this issue is time-sensitive.
Disclaimer #2: I'm basing the legitimacy of this cross-post on [advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251469/should-i-ask-questions-that-have-been-answered-on-other-qa-sites/251475#251475) found on the subject from Meta.
With that preamble...*</sup>

Up until now, I have been been using WS_FTP but would like to switch to WinSCP. 
I'm trying to convert this WS_FTP script into WinSCP:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\WS_FTP 12\wsftppro.exe"
-s "sftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftpus.pointclickcare.com/USERNAME/logs/*.sqb"
-d "local:C:\PccDataRelay\LogDownloads\"
-rename tx_[yyyy]-[mm]-[dd]_[hh]-[tt]-[ss]_[OnlyName].[OnlyExt]
-move "/USERNAME/logs/transferred/"
```

I've been able to convert it partially:

```
cd C:\PccDataRelay\TestDownloads

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /ini=nul /log=C:\PccDataRelay\AuditLogs\incremental_download.log /command ^
    "open sftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftpus.pointclickcare.com/USERNAME/logs/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx""" ^
    "get /USERNAME/logs/*.sqb" ^
    "exit"
```

But that only *downloads* the files. How can I get it to *rename* and *move* the original files while also leaving them in-place on the FTP site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinSCP does not have a feature similar to `-rename` and `-move` switches. So it's not easy to implement this task in a simple scripting so that it behaves transactionally (renames and moves only the files that were successfully downloaded)

---

But you can use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) from a [PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

```powershell
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "ftpus.pointclickcare.com"
    UserName = "USERNAME"
    Password = "PASSWORD"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="
}

# Connect
Write-Host "Connecting..."
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.SessionLogPath = "C:\PccDataRelay\AuditLogs\incremental_download.log"
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Download files
$transferResult =
    $session.GetFilesToDirectory(
        "/USERNAME/logs", "C:\PccDataRelay\LogDownloads", "*.sqb")

# Process source files
foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
{
    $oldName = $transfer.FileName
    # Success or error?
    if ($transfer.Error -eq $Null)
    {
        $newName =
            "/USERNAME/logs/transferred/tx_" +
            (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss") + "_" +
            [IO.Path]::GetFileName($oldName)
        Write-Host (
            "Download of $oldName succeeded, moving to backup $newName")
        $session.MoveFile($oldName, $newName)
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host (
            "Download of $oldName failed: $($transfer.Error.Message)")
    }
}
```

Some references that this answer is based on:

- [Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload#scripting);
- [Formatting timestamp in batch file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_formatting_timestamp_batch_file).

See also:

- [Converting WinSCP script to code based on .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_from_script).